# Issue interpreting JSON structure | Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have the following JSON structure that I am using to populate a tableView

I need to have my Swift app to be able to interpret the data correctly but for some reason, I cannot get it to work (tableView is empty)

**JSON Structure:**

```
    struct Pickup_EnRoute: Codable {
        let name, sumValue: String, sumTotal: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name
            case sumValue = "sumValue"
            case sumValue = "sumTotal"
        }
    }
```

**What the JSON looks like:**

```
[{"name":"Jake","sumValue":"10084.14"}, 
{"name":"Jack","sumValue":"9428.08"},{"sumTotal":19512.22}]
```

Notice how the sumTotal does not have " " (quotes) in the JSON array

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  struct Pickup_EnRoute: Codable {

    var name : String? 
    var sumValue: String?
    var sumTotal: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case sumValue = "sumValue"
        case sumTotal = "sumTotal"
    }
}
```

Change sumTotal String to Double.

Comment: It seemed to have worked but now when I assign the variable values such as sumValue to a UILable I get the word optional infront of the value. For example: `label.text = "$ \(portfolio.sumValue)"`

Comment: Portfolio is the name of the structure

Comment: use like this  if let sumValue = portfolio.sumValue {print(sumValue)}

Comment: How would it look like in the case of a label text value?

Comment: if let sumValue = portfolio.sumValue {label.text = "$  \ (sumValue)"}

Comment: Try `label.text = "$ \(portfolio.sumValue ?? "")"` for setting value in the `label`.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON "sumTotal" have type Double and your Structure you define sumTotal as type String. So change  sumTotal: String to  sumTotal: Double